# Codeigniter doesn't log all files names in error log

Tags: php, codeigniter, error-logging

I use this configuration to log errors

```
$config['log_threshold'] = 1;
```

the problem is some errors don't include the file name like this one while other errors include file name

```
ERROR - 2017-04-27 14:20:16 --> Query error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the 
manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'ORDER BY `id` DESC' at line 4 - Invalid query: SELECT COUNT(*) AS `numrows` FROM `orders`
WHERE `id` > ORDER BY `id` DESC

ERROR - 2017-04-27 14:20:16 --> Severity: Error --> Call to a member function num_rows() on 
boolean /home/username/public_html/system/database/DB_query_builder.php 1391
```

Why this happens and how to fix it. I found this answer [Codeigniter error log not including file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31703183/codeigniter-error-log-not-including-file-name) but can't find 'MY_Log.php'

Comment: You need to create the file `application/core/MY_Log.php`.

Answer (score 0):

I see the answer: [Codeigniter error log not including file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31703183/codeigniter-error-log-not-including-file-name) is very clear. Following these steps:

1. Create `MY_Log.php` file (remember `MY_Log.php` not `MY_log.php` or something else) in the `application/core` folder.
2. Copy the below code snippet and paste into that file:

   class MY_Log extends CI_Log {

   ```
   public function write_log($level, $msg)
   {
       foreach (debug_backtrace() as $call)
       {
           // Somehow find the appropriate call here ...
           if ( ! (/* condition to ignore error-handling calls */))
           {
               break;
           }

           $msg = '['.$call['file'].'] '.$msg;
           break;
       }

       return parent::write_log($level, $msg);
   }
   ```

   }
3. Save your file. Done!

Comment: Copy from the line: `class MY_Log extends CI_Log`

Comment: I did but no controller file name

Comment: No controller file name? what do you mean? Which CI version do you install?

Comment: some errors don't have the controller file name while others have controller file name as i mentioned. Version 3.0.3